# Retry loading an iframe until successful?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hey everyone new to web dev and getting stuck on how to handle when an iframe fails to load a src html file

When the user enters the page, *if the html file exists* it should load on the page as its own iframe. Otherwise, it should show a spinning icon until the html file exists (for context: I'm dynamically generating the graph on a separate thread which takes ~1 minute and cannot be prefetched).

How can I achieve this? I've tried adding the following tag which makes it always continuously reload the iframe, though that is all it does:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="test_examples/test1.html" height="650" width="800"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Continuously attempt to reload
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#iframe').attr('src', function (i,val) {return val;}); // resets iframe 
     },1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect your iframe title to detect if the iframe fails to load.

```js
var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
frame.onload = function(){
    if(frame.title !== "YourExpectedTitle"){ // Title checking
        $('#iframe').attr('src', function (i,val) {return val;}); // resets iframe
    }
}
```

Correct Me If Im Wrong